# Global optimization in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am new to Matlab and I want to write a matlab program for global optimization. I have an objective function `f(x)`, a domain `D`, and co-domain `R`. I have looked at *Optimization toolbox*, but it show reference and examples of local minimization only.

If someone can give me a few hints on global optimization in Matlab, that will be very helpful.

Comment: This not seems to be a programming issue! I believe you can find more help in studying the following docs for [Optimization toolbox](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.mathworks.it/help/releases/R13sp2/pdf_doc/optim/optim_tb.pdf&ei=bj38UPzZMcO7hAfhooG4DA&usg=AFQjCNHZZ2AhXZNOZcSdzwNQorVn3BFCPw&bvm=bv.41248874,d.ZG4): maximization is in section 2-16!

Answer (score 2):

Optimization Toolbox, as you've discovered, only handles "local" optimization - algorithms such as linear, quadratic and binary programming, nonlinear optimization etc. You might like to take a look at [Global Optimization Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/global-optimization/), which contains global optimization algorithms such as genetic algorithms, simulated annealing and others..